# C# SPOJ time optimalization

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm trying to get the job done MOHIBPIZ - PIZZA (https://www.spoj.com/problems/MOHIBPIZ/).
I'm already sitting on it the second day, I've tried everything I can and found on the internet. The last chance before giving up is to ask you guys
For recudces time I'm using InputOutput class created by davidsekar (https://github.com/davidsekar/C-sharp-Programming-IO/blob/master/ConsoleInOut/InputOutput.cs)
but still I have time "time limit exceeded". :(

I tried with two loops, but the method with the function seems more optimal to me. Thanks in advance for all the hints, suggestions and answers.

This is code (link on ideone: https://ideone.com/):

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        InputOutput reader = new InputOutput();
        StreamWriter _output = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());

        int T = reader.ReadInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
        {
            _output.WriteLine(Recursion(reader.ReadInt()));
        }
        _output.Flush();
    }

    private static int Recursion(int x)
    {
        if(x <= 1)
        {
            return 2;
        }
        else
        {
            return Recursion(x - 1) + x;
        }
    }

    #region Input Output Helper 
    public class InputOutput : System.IDisposable
    {
        private System.IO.Stream _readStream, _writeStream;
        private int _readIdx, _bytesRead, _writeIdx, _inBuffSize, _outBuffSize;
        private readonly byte[] _inBuff, _outBuff;
        private readonly bool _bThrowErrorOnEof;

        public void SetBuffSize(int n)
        {
            _inBuffSize = _outBuffSize = n;
        }

        public InputOutput(bool throwEndOfInputsError = false)
        {
            _readStream = System.Console.OpenStandardInput();
            _writeStream = System.Console.OpenStandardOutput();
            _readIdx = _bytesRead = _writeIdx = 0;
            _inBuffSize = _outBuffSize = 1 << 22;
            _inBuff = new byte[_inBuffSize];
            _outBuff = new byte[_outBuffSize];
            _bThrowErrorOnEof = throwEndOfInputsError;
        }

        public void SetFilePath(string strPath)
        {
            strPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(strPath);
            _readStream = System.IO.File.Open(strPath, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
        }

        public T ReadNumber<T>()
        {
            byte rb;
            while ((rb = GetByte()) < '-')
                ;

            var neg = false;
            if (rb == '-')
            {
                neg = true;
                rb = GetByte();
            }
            dynamic m = (T)Convert.ChangeType(rb - '0', typeof(T));
            while (true)
            {
                rb = GetByte();
                if (rb < '0')
                    break;
                m = m * 10 + (rb - '0');
            }
            return neg ? -m : m;
        }

        public int ReadInt()
        {
            byte readByte;
            while ((readByte = GetByte()) < '-')
                ;

            var neg = false;
            if (readByte == '-')
            {
                neg = true;
                readByte = GetByte();
            }
            var m = readByte - '0';
            while (true)
            {
                readByte = GetByte();
                if (readByte < '0')
                    break;
                m = m * 10 + (readByte - '0');
            }
            return neg ? -m : m;
        }

        public string ReadString()
        {
            return ReadString(' ');
        }

        public string ReadString(string delimiter)
        {
            return ReadString(delimiter[0]);
        }

        public string ReadString(char delimiter)
        {
            byte readByte;
            while ((readByte = GetByte()) <= delimiter)
                ;

            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            do
            {
                sb.Append((char)readByte);
            } while ((readByte = GetByte()) > delimiter);

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImpl(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        private byte GetByte()
        {
            if (_readIdx >= _bytesRead)
            {
                _readIdx = 0;
                _bytesRead = _readStream.Read(_inBuff, 0, _inBuffSize);
                if (_bytesRead >= 1)
                    return _inBuff[_readIdx++];

                if (_bThrowErrorOnEof)
                    throw new System.Exception("End Of Input");
                _inBuff[_bytesRead++] = 0;
            }
            return _inBuff[_readIdx++];
        }

        public void WriteToBuffer(string s)
        {
            foreach (var b in System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s))
            {
                if (_writeIdx == _outBuffSize)
                    Flush();
                _outBuff[_writeIdx++] = b;
            }
        }

        public void WriteLineToBuffer(string s)
        {
            WriteToBuffer(s);
            if (_writeIdx == _outBuffSize)
                Flush();
            _outBuff[_writeIdx++] = 10;
        }

        public void WriteToBuffer(int c)
        {
            byte[] temp = new byte[10];
            int tempidx = 0;
            if (c < 0)
            {
                if (_writeIdx == _outBuffSize)
                    Flush();
                _outBuff[_writeIdx++] = (byte)'-';
                c = -c;
            }
            do
            {
                temp[tempidx++] = (byte)((c % 10) + '0');
                c /= 10;
            } while (c > 0);
            for (int i = tempidx - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (_writeIdx == _outBuffSize)
                    Flush();
                _outBuff[_writeIdx++] = temp[i];
            }
        }

        public void WriteLineToBuffer(int c)
        {
            WriteToBuffer(c);
            if (_writeIdx == _outBuffSize)
                Flush();
            _outBuff[_writeIdx++] = 10;
        }

        private void Flush()
        {
            _writeStream.Write(_outBuff, 0, _writeIdx);
            _writeStream.Flush();
            _writeIdx = 0;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Flush();
            _writeStream.Close();
            _readStream.Close();
        }
    }
    #endregion Input Output Helper 

}
```

Comment: `result = (n * n + n + 2) / 2;` see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleDivisionbyLines.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you have a well known [Circle Division problem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleDivisionbyLines.html); see also [A000124](http://oeis.org/A000124) sequence:

number of pieces after `n` cuts are `(n * n + n + 2) / 2`

That's why we can put `O(1)` time and space complexity

**Code:**

```
private static int Solution(int n) => (int)(((long)n * n + n + 2) / 2);
```

Here I've put `(long) n` in case `n * n` *exceeds* `int.MaxValue`, when `(n * n + n + 2) / 2` doesn't.

**Edit:** I've implemented `int Solution(int n)` method which is based on current code `int Recursion(int x)` *signature*; but if there're tests for *large* `n` we are going to have *integer overflow*.
In this case

```
 private static long Solution(long n) =>
   1 + (n % 2 == 0 ? n / 2 * (n + 1) : (n + 1) / 2 * n);
```

In case of arbitrary `n` we have to use `BigInteger`:

```
 using System.Numerics;

 ...

 private static BigInteger Solution(BigInteger n) =>
   1 + (n * n + n) / 2;
```

Comment: thanks for answer, I tried this method earlier but like now I have "Wrong answer" . I tested it on my onw, not too much because only 52 cases but all was correct. I don't understand what's wrong :/ I changed my class "Recursion" for your Solution. Ideone: https://ideone.com/Y2CAex

Comment: @KaMeR: can you provide a *counter example*? A failed test?

Comment: @KaMeR: may be we have just an integer overflow, let's return `long`, not `int`: `private static long Solution(int n) => ((long)n * n + n + 2) / 2; `

Comment: I tried find failed test but its 10^9 cases.

Comment: You have right, that was an error, we need long because int is too small. Thank you very much